# MVC3 CustomRoleProvider Dependency Injection Issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ninject

I'm trying to create a custom RoleProvider in my MVC3 project. My RoleProvider is defined as follows:

```
public class MyRoleProvider : System.Web.Security.RoleProvider
{
    private IAccountService _accountService;

    public MyRoleProvider()
    {
        _accountService = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IAccountService>();
    }

    //...
}
```

As you can see, I'm trying to use the DependencyResolver to get my binded service. My binding is done in my App_Start:

```
private static IKernel CreateKernel()
{
    var kernel = new StandardKernel();
    kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
    kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();

    RegisterServices(kernel);
    return kernel;
}

private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    // Add data and infrastructure modules
    var modules = new List<INinjectModule>
    {
        new ConfigModule(),
        new LoggingModule(),
        new RepositoryModule(),
        new ServiceModule()
    };
    kernel.Load(modules);
}
```

ServiceModule is where im doing the actual binding:

```
public class ServiceModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Kernel.Bind<ICoreService>().To<CoreService>();
        Kernel.Bind<IAccountService>().To<AccountService>();
    }
}
```

My problem is that when I debug the website, I'm getting a configuration error:

Configuration Error

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

Source Error:

```
Line 45:     <roleManager>
Line 46:       <providers>
Line 47:         <clear />
Line 48:         <add name="MyRoleProvider" type="Project.Web.Ui.Helpers.MyRoleProvider, Project.Web.Ui" connectionStringName="MyConnection" />
Line 49:       </providers>
Line 50:     </roleManager>
```

If I place a breakpoint on my role providers constructor:

> _accountService = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService();

and I place a breakpoint on my App_Start Dependency Injector:

> var kernel = new StandardKernel();

The _accountService breakpoint hits first, but if I try to step over or step in, it just blows up. Any thoughts on what I might be doing wrong or any ideas on figuring out a way to dig deeper?

Edit: I'm assuming that the reason is because my Dependency Injector has not bound my services to the interfaces and the DependencyResolver doesn't know about the binding.

Comment: I'm guessing that I have to use this: DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel)); but how do I use that since my Kernel is not being created first?